# How can I search for a single inserted item without the other's?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
create procedure SearchUsers(@User_name varchar(50),
                             @User_cellPhone varchar(10 ) null,
                             @Is_Active bit null)

declare @boolean varchar(50) = @Is_active
set @boolean = CAST(@boolean as varchar)

select [User_Name],User_CellNumber,User_FirstName
from [User]
where (
           [User_Name] like '%'+ @User_name + '%' 
       and User_CellNumber like '%' + @User_cellPhone + '%' 
       and User_IsActive like '%' + @boolean + '%' 
      ) 
order by [User_Name]
```

Please assist me on how I can search for a user by only using `@User_name` or all the above mentioned.

Comment: Take a look at this article. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: And why in the world are taking a bit, then putting the value into a varchar (which btw has no length specified) and then comparing what is most likely another bit field using like with wildcards? For that matter, why do you have leading wildcards on every predicate? That is a recipe for a super slow query.

Comment: there is no need of any conversion between boolean and varchar. 1. instead of Is_Active bit null, it should be Is_Active bit = false.. by default bit field if *false* or *0*. Second, do you want to select one user who meets the criteria or set of users?

Comment: Amnesh Goel : I want the admin to search for a user who is either active or not active, admin can search either using their name or cellphone or both....Admin can search for user who are active starting with the letter B

Comment: Sean Lange : the link  helped thanks

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, there is NO need to convert a bit to a varchar. Since I don't have all the facts, I left all your wildcards, but you should only use the wildcards you need so they don't slow down your query. Try this out:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SearchUsers(@User_name         VARCHAR(50),
                             @User_cellPhone    VARCHAR(10) NULL,
                             @Is_Active         BIT         NULL)
AS
SELECT [User_Name],User_CellNumber,User_FirstName
FROM [User]
WHERE       (
                    [User_Name]     LIKE '%' + @User_name + '%'
                AND @User_cellPhone IS NULL
                AND @Is_Active      IS NULL
        OR  (
                    [User_Name]     LIKE '%' + @User_name + '%'         
                AND User_CellNumber LIKE '%' + @User_cellPhone + '%' 
                AND User_IsActive   = @Is_Active
            )
GO
```